# Remove an item from Firebase with AngularFire $remove method

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I have the following data array in my Firebase app. I want to delete Account3 using AngularFire's $remove method but I can't get it to work

```
[MY-FIREBASE-URL]
  users
    simplelogin:1
      accounts
        0
          title: "Account1"
        1
          title: "Account2"
        2
          title: "Account3"
        3
          title: "Account4"
        4
          title: "Account5"
```

This is the code I'm using

```
var fbURL = [MY-FIREBASE-URL];
var ref = new Firebase(fbURL);
var authData = ref.getAuth();
if (authData) {
     console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
     var accountPath = fbURL + "/users/" + authData.uid + "/accounts/" + account.title;
     //alert(accountPath);
     var accountRef = new Firebase(accountPath);
     accountRef.remove();
     } else {
          console.log("User is logged out");
     }
```

In the console.log I see the correct user in the authData but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I altered the `accountRef` variable and your `$remove()` function:

```
var fbURL = [MY-FIREBASE-URL];
var ref = new Firebase(fbURL);
var authData = ref.getAuth();
if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
    var accountPath = fbURL + "/users/" + authData.uid + "/accounts/" + account.title;
    //alert(accountPath);
    var accountRef = $firebaseObject(accountPath);
    accountRef.$remove().then(function(accountPath) {
        console.log("data has been deleted locally and in Firebase");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
    });
} else {
      console.log("User is logged out");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MattDionis for you help. I finally found the answer to my question so here it is for any other newbies like me struggling with a similar issue. In the sample code above the Firebase URL was referencing "account.title" which in fact I needed "account.id", based on the data structure above, to actually remove the entry from my Firebase data.